# HAProxy configuration ports issue

Tags: linux, load-balancing, haproxy

Hi :) I have problem with HAProxy configuration. I have haproxy and two backend servers (backend servers listen on 1234 port)

It's my haproxu config:

```
frontend http_front
 bind *:80

backend http_back
 balance roundrobin
 server server1 10.0.0.2:1234
 server server2 10.0.0.3:1234
```

This config doesn't work, but when i add to frontend:

```
bind *:1234
```

It works great - i don't understand it because bind *:1234 inform only haproxy to listen on 1234 port nothing more. Have you any advices or explanations ?

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is a privileged port, this means that you can only start haproxy as root when you want that haproxy should listen on port 80.
Another reason could be that there is another server listen on port 80. Maybe a web server run also on this machine which listens on port 80.

Comment: No, HAProxy is binding on port 80, but not forward traffic to backend without **bind *:1234**

Comment: on which os are you? is there any security engine which needs to be adopted that haproxy is allowed to bind to port 80? what's in the haproxy logs?